New AI camera not working on 3 Model B+ and Zero 2
I have been following the official instructions on the latest 32-bit OS:
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

The simple check on the camera rpicam-hello gives
[0:09:50.045272242] [2022]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:325 libcamera v0.3.2+27-7330f29b
Preview window unavailable
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***

I have confirmed that the camera port of the Pi and the ribbon cable are working using another camera.
The official instrucutions do mention that "With minor changes, you can follow these instructions on other Raspberry Pi models with a camera connector, including the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W and Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+". Has anybody figured what those "minor changes" are?
Any help in this regard would be great!

nowhere on those instructions is there mention of 32 or 64bit OS - the fact that only pi zero 2 and pi3 are mentioned strongly implies that you may need a 64bit install ... also, the error you show suggests your camera isn't even detected, so it's probably not physically installed correctly

Hi @JaromandaX, I have 2 AI Cameras and they both have the same issue so I don't think the cameras are busted. The ports and cables are working fine, I have confirmed with other spare "regular" cameras.

Re OS, all I imply is that I have tested on both 32 and 64-bit systems to confirm if it's got anything to do with compatibility

OK, of course I didn't know you had 2 AI cameras, I didn't know you tested other cameras to be working, nor did I know that you tested both 32bit Raspbian and 64bit Debian - but now that is clarified, it rules out a lot of potential issues, making answering the question a little easier

Folks at Raspberry Pi have confirmed that it's a firmware issue. Some of the AI Cams were shipped with the older RP2040 v14 firmware and updating this to v15 would solve the problem.
Guide to updating the firmware is on this RPi forum thread.
PS this discussion thread can be useful to some.
Cheers,
PC
